# Filter row to only contain values from 'Today' until Sunday

Tags: excel, vba

We have a weekly function where we need to ensure the data included contains only values from the day the report is created until the coming Sunday. I know the issue I am having is that my `EndDate` value is unable to be formatted to `yyyy-mm-dd`, but I do not know how to go forward. This is what I have:

```
' set value for 'EndDate'
Dim EndDate As Date
    EndDate = DateAdd("d", -Weekday(Now) + 8, Now)
    
' reformat 'Required End' column to "yyyy-mm-dd"
ActiveSheet.Range("F2", "F50000").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"

' filter results from StartDate to EndDate
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, _
                               Criteria1:=">=" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd"), _
                               Operator:=xlAnd, _
                               Criteria2:="<=" & Format(EndDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

I am receiving the error:
`Run time error '9': Subscript out of range`

Comment: You probably don't have a table (listobject) on the active sheet.

Comment: *`EndDate` value is unable to be formatted to `yyyy-mm-dd`* That will not cause the error you report.  In addition, use `CDbl(your_date)` for your various comparisons instead of a formatted string.